# Laravel/Lumen file response

Tags: laravel-5, php-7, lumen

I need to stream file content (such as images and other mime types) from a Lumen resource server to a Laravel client server. I know in Laravel I can use:

```
$headers = ['Content-Type' => 'image/png']; 
$path = storage_path('/mnt/somestorage/example.png')
return response()->file($path, $headers);
```

However, the `file` method is absent in `Laravel\Lumen\Http\ResponseFactory`.

Any suggestions are very welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Lumen you can use Symfony's `BinaryFileResponse`.

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse

$type = 'image/png';
$headers = ['Content-Type' => $type];
$path = '/path/to/you/your/file.png';

$response = new BinaryFileResponse($path, 200 , $headers);

return $response;
```

You can [find the documentation here](https://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/BinaryFileResponse.html).

Comment: Perfect, this was very useful to me today :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in Lumen:
https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#file-downloads

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Attachment;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AttachmentController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * Downloads related document by id
     */
    public function attachment(Request $request)
    {
        $path = "path/to/file.pdf";
        return response()->download($path);
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because it is less code and it works :-)

Comment: Feel like its worth adding that using response()->download will get the browser to download the file, but with a BinaryFileResponse as in the currently accepted answer you can show the file in a tab if the file type is supported, e.g. PDF in my case, either are acceptable depending on your use case.